# CAF page header not showing up for sysadmin user

Tags: portlet, webmethods, composite-application

I have a webMethods MWS server, when I am logging in with sysadmin user the header and footer tab is not showing up.

Error page looks like this -

[image]

While the correct page looks like this from another MWS server -
[image]

Can someone help me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The sysadmin shell is called 'Power Drill Shell'. It's not supposed to editable.
Maybe your Shell Rule 'Sys Admin' has been edited. The rule should be:

```
(("Admin Role" matches user.groupMembershipDNs) or ("Admin Role" matches user.roleMembershipDNs))
```